# WPF plugin system - Dependency injection in plugin class libraries

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, wpf, plugins, plugin-architecture

The main application loads plugins, list them and when user selects one it is initialized and displayed. Each plugin is a complex class library which contains several views/viewmodels/repositories/etc..

Is it a good idea in such a case to have in each plugin some kind of a bootstrapper and use dependency injection directly in a class library in order to inject dependencies to plugin`s Viewmodels/Repositories (for example repositories into viewmodels)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

Normally passing the dependency container around is a no-no as it doesn't expose the required dependencies to the calling code you have no way to know what dependencies to populate your container with.

However, if you are dynamically loading plugins you won't know anyway! So having a `ContainerContainsEverythingINeed(container)` and a `BootStrapPlugin(container)` doesn't seem like a bad choice if you force all your plugins to implement them.

You might have some worries about plugins sharing dependencies or seeing things you don't want them to. But you can always have multiple dependency injection containers if required.

Comment: In regards to the second paragraph, let's use the example of AutoMapper here, are you saying that `services.AddAutoMapper()` is an antipattern and we should instead be registering the internal components of the AutoMapper library ourselves? Because that's something I as a developer (a) don't care about and (b) don't want to be tasked with whenever AutoMapper releases an update. And then the same applies to our own dependent projects and plugins: passing the container allows the individual components to register their own private details that others don't necessarily need to know about.

Comment: that's a bit of a side question, but yes it is an anti pattern. For exactly the reasons you mention. you have hidden all the dependencies config and options in a private methods and only exposed them to your static AddXXX call. breaks the O in solid amongst many other things

Comment: not sure its relevant here because I think we can generally assume that sevices.AddXXX() and only adding dependencies. whereas in this case we are pulling them